# Allowing only cloudflare i.p range through .htaccess giving 403 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cloudflare

I've been trying to allow only cloudflares i.p ranges on my server but I keep getting 403 errors, 403 is what people bypassing cloudfare should see

I have tried

```
    #cloudflare
    order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    #ipv4
    allow from 173.245.48.0/20
    allow from 103.21.244.0/22
    allow from 103.22.200.0/22
    allow from 103.31.4.0/22
    allow from 141.101.64.0/18
    allow from 108.162.192.0/18
    allow from 190.93.240.0/20
    allow from 188.114.96.0/20
    allow from 197.234.240.0/22
    allow from 198.41.128.0/17
    allow from 162.158.0.0/15
    allow from 104.16.0.0/12
    allow from 172.64.0.0/13
    allow from 131.0.72.0/22
    #ipv6
    allow from 2400:cb00::/32
    allow from 2606:4700::/32
    allow from 2803:f800::/32
    allow from 2405:b500::/32
    allow from 2405:8100::/32
    allow from 2a06:98c0::/29
    allow from 2c0f:f248::/32
```

and I have tried

```
    DenyAllButCloudFlare
```

I get the same issue, the above line gives me 500 error

for the life of me I cant figure it out, cloudflare support just referred me to there whitelist page which I have followed

I'm using Apache 2.4.2

edit: changed Apache version num :)

Comment: I think you mean that your Apache version is 2.4.2, right?

Comment: Try using the `Require` directive in Apache. Apache themselves mention:  ***The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.***  Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: thanks guys will read through them now

Comment: @MattWillis I have answered your question. Check it out. Ask me if any doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Require directive in Apache. Apache themselves mention:

> The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

Try changing it to, and make sure mod_authz_host is enabled:

```
#path to your website
<Directory "path/to/public_html/or/var/www/html">
    #ipv4
    Require ip 173.245.48.0/20
    Require ip 103.21.244.0/22
    Require ip 103.22.200.0/22
    Require ip 103.31.4.0/22
    Require ip 141.101.64.0/18
    Require ip 108.162.192.0/18
    Require ip 190.93.240.0/20
    Require ip 188.114.96.0/20
    Require ip 197.234.240.0/22
    Require ip 198.41.128.0/17
    Require ip 162.158.0.0/15
    Require ip 104.16.0.0/12
    Require ip 172.64.0.0/13
    Require ip 131.0.72.0/22
    #ipv6
    Require ip 2400:cb00::/32
    Require ip 2606:4700::/32
    Require ip 2803:f800::/32
    Require ip 2405:b500::/32
    Require ip 2405:8100::/32
    Require ip 2a06:98c0::/29
    Require ip 2c0f:f248::/32
</Directory>
```

Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html for more info.

Be aware of this: Cloudflare themselves say: I think it should be better just using the normal Apache directives anyways

> Cloudflare no longer updates and supports mod_cloudflare, starting with versions Debian 9 *and *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS of the Linux operating system. We now support mod_remoteip for customers using Apache web servers. Customers who are interested in building the mod_cloudflare package can download the codebase from GitHub.

See: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170916-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-Option-1-Installing-mod-cloudflare

And mod_remoteip feels like it is insecure. So, I suggest you to stick with the Require ip directive.

Comment: same issue with that bud, but i did resolve it adding the DenyAllButCloudFlare to httpd.conf, thanks anyway

Comment: Do not add any of these to htaccess

Comment: Maybe you could accept this as answer. But you should probably look for better ones.

Comment: @MattWillis it must also work without mod_cloudflare.

Comment: Be aware of this btw. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170916-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-Option-1-Installing-mod-cloudflare

Comment: thanks for that, il remove the older one and install that

Comment: hi mate so to confirm i add the require list to the httpd.conf? also there is not authz host but there is mod_authz_dbd , mod_authz_dbm and mod_authz_owner

Comment: It should exist. I am sure. Something might be wrong with your Apache conf. But don't worry. Maybe check out https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html for more info. I have it in my httpd.conf. What OS are you using btw?

Comment: hi im using centos 7, i could prob install auth host manually through ssh

Comment: probably. not so sure about centos 7.

Comment: hi mate, so after checking it was installed anyway, not sure why it does not appear in easyapache, ive entered your require list and there is not 403 for me now, do i need to add some sort of deny line to stop any other i.ps accessing the server?

Comment: Ask in forums.cpanel.net, i guess you are using cPanel.

Comment: You will get answers that are suitable for EasyApache.

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe that updated one will work.